# Как вызвать функцию Win Forms приложения из console?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

Нужно запустить приложение Win forms из командной строки cmd и передать параметры на выполнение функции, графический интерфейс при этом не должен запускаться.

Comment: А само WinForms приложение вам доступно в виде исходников?

Comment: WinForm приложение сам написал, но тут встала задача запускать функцию приложения из командной строки... Весь день гуглю и нужное найти не могу.

Comment: @Macro: Разделите приложение на графическую часть и логику. Сделайте так, чтобы в приложении логика была не внутри окна (боже упаси!), а в отдельном модуле. Тогда вы сможете при старте проанализировать ключи командной строки, при необходимости просто выполнить нужную функцию и выйти, а если ключей нет, запускать ваш UI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Без некоторой переделки `WinForms` приложения не получится. Итак, идем в файл `Program.cs`

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

И делаем немного магии:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    const int SW_SHOW = 5;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //параметр может звучать произвольно по вашему желанию
        if (args.Contains("-nowindow"))
        {
            // выполняем то что нужно
            // хорошо если в приложении хорошая архитектура и логика от
            // представления разделена - все будет проще
            // Иначе переделывать придется многое.
            // как-то так, удачи =)
            Console.WriteLine("Привет");
            Console.WriteLine("Введите дату начала:");
            var t = Console.ReadLine();
            var startDay = new DateTime();
            DateTime.TryParse(t, out startDay);
            Console.WriteLine(startDay);
            //something else
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
        else
        {

            //если параметра -nowindow нет то стартуем как обычно
            var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

**Не забываем** переключить тип выходных данных в свойствах проекта на `Консольное приложение`.

Comment: Да вот как раз о данном знал, а просят чтоб запустили программу. И там дальше надо вводить начальную дату и конечную дату в разных строках. Далее естественно отрабатывала функция по данным входным параметрам. Но ведь args.Contains не может быть динамическим на сколько я знаю.

Comment: ну так заускайте так myProg.exe /nowindow /par1 10.11.1987 /par2 01.05.1999 /par3 49. Достаточно обрабатывать эти параметры и все нужные данные таким образом без проблем можно передать - они будут массивом. Если нужно интерактив - то пожалуйста. Работайте как в обчном консольном приложении `Console.WriteLine()`, `Console.ReadKey` - это всё.

Comment: C Консолью я погорячился, она там несколько нетривиально прикручивается. Так что в не интерактивном режиме с параметрами как батя завещал)

Comment: Обновил ответ - консоль прикрутил.

Comment: **Нельзя так делать.** Вы скрываете консоль даже если этой консолью пользуется кто-то еще.